# RegEx: Combine two expressions

Tags: regex, validation

I have an .net Aspx page which has several validators. One of the inputs can now have two types of validation dependant on the value of a previously set dropdown.

The original validation was `[a-sA-Z09]{1}[a-sA-Z09]{1}$` which worked fine giving me any combination of letter or digit twice i.e AR, 00, 91, S5, 7Y are all valid.

Now I have to add the following `0-9{3}$` which will validate upto 3 digits only i.e 1, 21, 176, 999 are all valid so are 002 and 078.

How do I combine the two expressions in one so that the input will match one or other expression? Should I try the 3 digit match first and the the 2 character match if the 3 digit fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your original expressions are broken. Try this:

```
^([a-sA-Z0-9]{2}|[0-9]{0,3})$
```

This will match two characters, `a` through `s` <sub><sup>(did you mean `z`?)</sup></sub>, `A` through `Z`, or `0` through `9` ***or*** up to three characters `0` through `9`.